# I get a ' no module named django ' error on heroku only when i try to submit an email form yet locally it works just fine

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I pip freeze on heroku console i find that django has been installed.
When i try to submit the form locally on my computer the submission is successful with no errors.

**Views.py**

```
    '''

    @login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def b_contact(request):
c_form = ContactForm
if request.method == 'POST':
    c_form = ContactForm(data=request.POST)
    if c_form.is_valid():
        email = c_form.cleaned_data['email']
        subject = c_form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = c_form.cleaned_data['message'] 
        send_mail(email, message, subject, ['be.rightmuk@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
        messages.success(request, f'Your message has been sent!')
        return redirect('buyer_home')
else:
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    subject = request.POST.get('subject')
    message = request.POST.get('message')

context = {
    'c_form': c_form
} 

return render(request, 'buyer/contact.html', context)
```

'''

**forms.py**

```
 class ContactForm(forms.Form):
email = forms.EmailField(label='Your Email')
subject = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=150)
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

**tepmplate**

```
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">

        {{ c_form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>

        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Send </button>

</form>
```

**requirements.txt**

```
 dj-database-url==0.5.0
 Django==2.0
 django-bootstrap3==11.0.0
 django-bootstrap4==1.0.1
 django-braces==1.13.0
 django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
 django-heroku==0.3.1
 django-model-utils==3.2.0
 django-progressive-web-app==0.1.1
 django-registration==2.4.1
 django-tinymce==2.8.0
 djangorestframework==3.9.4
 gunicorn==19.9.0
```

**This is the error**

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /seller/contact/
No module named "'django"
Request Method: POST
Request URL:     
https://sakka.herokuapp.com/seller/contact/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
No module named "'django"
Exception Location: <frozen importlib._bootstrap> in 
_find_and_load_unlocked, line 953
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.8
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
'   /app',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 24 Oct 2019 15:06:42 +0300
```

This error only comes when i try to post some information from my contact form otherwise everything else works just fine